# Adding avg line to bar plot using read_excel, pandas, matplotlib

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code to produce a bar graph of daily rainfall for a given month across multiple years.

```
df=pd.read_excel(("C:/Filepath/RainData.xls"), \
             sheetname=sheet,\
             header=0,\
             parse_cols="B:BD",\
             na_values='T')

precip = df.loc[31, :]


precipavg=((sum(precip[1:]))/(len(precip[1:])))
print(precipavg)

df.head(0)
fig,ax= plt.subplots()

precip.plot(kind="bar",ax=ax, color='g',figsize=(15,7))

plt.minorticks_on()
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',bottom='off')
ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Precipitation")
ax.set_title((filename+" Precipitation"), fontsize=20)
```

I would like to then add on top of this bar graph a single line indicating avergae rainfall for the month. I have calculated this using the precipavg line above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can employ [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html) as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(20, 1)), columns=["rain"])

# your plot setup
fig,ax= plt.subplots()

df.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax, color='g',figsize=(15,7))

plt.minorticks_on()
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',bottom='off')
ax.set_xlabel("Year")
ax.set_ylabel("Precipitation")
ax.set_title(("Precipitation"), fontsize=20)

# use axhline
mean = df["rain"].mean()
ax.axhline(mean)
```

[image]